# how to handle cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'base-package' must appear on element 'context:component-scan'

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring and hiberent my spring config file throws Exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/> 
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> 
  </bean>
   <context:component-scan></context:component-scan>
   </beans>
```

it's give cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'base-package' must appear on element 'context:component-scan'.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the error infomation, you need to add component-scan like this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.service"/>
```

to tell spring to scan the package and add all the bean annotation with 
@Component, @Service, @Controller and so on to spring context;

If you add annotation above to your class in this base package, this bean can be used in spring context.